# After installing react navigation 5.x app is getting crashed all the time

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have installed "npm install @react-navigation/native" and all the dependencies with it "npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view". After installation when I build the app and , its building successfully but getting crashed after installing on my phone.

when I uninstall the dependency react-native-safe-area-context, app is running but it suppose to be needed to use react navigation.

I am using windows machine, testing on my android phone.

package.json

```
{
"name": "Money",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"android": "react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios",
"start": "react-native start",
"test": "jest",
"lint": "eslint ."
},
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.5",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.0.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.5",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
"react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
"babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
"eslint": "^6.5.1",
"jest": "^24.9.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
"react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
}
```

Comment: hi in terminal goto android folder(cd android) and then clean gradlew (./gradlew clean) then cd .. and run react-native run android.

Comment: Try to manually link the modals maybe autolinking failed

Comment: @AmirFarahani already tried, but did not worked.

Comment: @yesIamFaded did not worked, facing same issue.

Comment: what's an error in console? please update your question

Comment: @AmirFarahani nothing is showing in console, its showing building 100% (metro server)

Comment: can u add app.js code

Comment: @AshwithSaldanha I have the basic code what react-native provides after creating an app. Bare minimum app.

Comment: please remove node_module folder and npm install (yarn install) again

Comment: Any errors you got in device ? or Crashing means that App Stopped Working ?

Comment: Please attach error / issue screenshot if you can ( Device Crash or Something )

Comment: @AkilaDevinda when I am trying to open the app on my phone, its opening for 2 second and closed again. No err is coming on my phone or console

Answer (score 2):

Solved this issue by doing this work around.

Can confirm, crashing immediately after launch on Android, no problems on iOS.
It seems there is a Java class missing.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout;

Add the following dependencies to app/build.gradle to avoid this error:

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha03'

[Check this link](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6892#issuecomment-588113613)